# Linux-NTP Leap Seconds : Decreasing time to apply leap file

Tags: linux, time, ntp, ntpd

Is there any way to make NTP process and apply the leap second file faster than it currently does?

I am writing an application which is dependent on CLOCK_TAI. It would be a mistake to allow the application to execute if the tai_offset is unset.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 I have a leap second file (http://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/leap-seconds.list) installed and ntp (4.2.6p5) configured to use it.

Using a test program which compares CLOCK_TAI with CLOCK_REALTIME, I find it takes over 4 minutes until the tai_offset is changed after restarting ntp with the new configuration.

I would like to significantly reduce this time.